# Trying to find a (jquery?) popup date/time selector with callback to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a large table with input boxes.

Three columns of these are dates/times (in unix format).

Im trying to find an easy to implement way of allowing the user to click on this box, being able to (graphically) select a date/time, and when done, sending the selection to a php script to make the physical changes of the data. (i can convert the date/time back to unix from here if necessary).

The caveat is that each input is named dynamically according to its row number.

Here is my script where i output the date fields

```
}elseif(in_array($j, array(19,33,54))){
    echo "<td><input type=text value=\"$value\" name=\"date$j\" class=med></td></td>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to integrate the jQuery datepicker, but what you need to do is some kind of ajax call to the PHP!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI datepicker supports a great number of options and events including an [on-select event](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-onSelect). It's also possible to have a datepicker attached to a hidden input with a separate activation control, so there's no problem at all with using it for AJAX.

Comment: how would i handle the problem of the multiple dynamic inputs?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the problem is? I don't see one. Each input would get its own datepicker, and you know what the input's name is, so just... do whatever you need to do.

Comment: When i apply this to my page, only the first input triggers the datepicker. None of the other inputs work.

Comment: Then you have an error in your code that doesn't relate directly to datepicker. Datepicker can be applied to as many elements as you like.